# Open new popup if tab is close event

Tags: javascript, html, popup

i just want to open a new popup if the browserwindow is closed.
i have following code, but it doesnt seem to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
         window.open("http://www.w3schools.com"); 
    }
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: Works fine for me, what browser are you using and what are you trying to acvhieve with this?

Comment: im using firefox 18 and safari 6 and it doesnt work! i want to get a  popup window if the actual site closes. eg im on a page and pressing the x of a tab, a popup appears!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `onUnload` event, not `onBeforeUnload`.

`onBeforeUnload` is expected to return a string which is used in an automatic confirm window.
Word of warning, most pop up blockers will ignore calls to `window.open` executed from an `onUnload` event.

See [the mdc documentation here for `onUnload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload) and [here for `onBeforeUnload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

Comment: is there any way to get the window.open with popup blocker? the unload works on a reload, but i only get the "a popup was blocked" text. how to fix that? thanks :)

Comment: Circumventing pop up blockers isn't a very good idea for usability.  Many users find them annoying and this is why pop up blockers are so prevalent (even built into browsers).

Answer (score 0):

The function you set as window.onbeforeunload must return a string that will be shown to the user in a messagebox.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
     window.open("http://www.w3schools.com"); 
return "something";
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work, i only get the "something" string, not a popup with the www.w3schools.com...

Comment: I tried it on jsfiddle.net and it creates a popup, it's just that Chrome blocks it. Check if your browser isn't blocking it as well.

Comment: it only works on safari, and not as popup. it obens a new tab... i tried firefox and chrome...